# CSS "and" and "or"

Tags: css, css-selectors, conditional-operator

I've got quite big trouble, because i need to anathematise from styling some input types. I had something like:

```
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio")
{
 //Nah.
}
```

But i don't want to style checkboxes too.

I've tried:

```
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio" && type="checkbox"])
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio" && "checkbox"])
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio") && .registration_form_right input:not(type="checkbox"])
```

How to use `&&`? And I'll need to use `||` soon, and I think that usage will be same.

**Update:**
I still don't know how to use `||` and `&&` correctly. I couldn't find anything in W3 docs.

Comment: *"anathematise"* Yikes. You want to threaten people attempting to style checkboxes with devine retribution? (You probably meant "exempt" or similar, e.g., "I need to exempt some input types from a styling rule.")

Comment: Well, i couldn't find good translation to phrasal verb from my language ;)

Comment: I think @T.J. Crowder probably understood that. But it *was* funny...particularly the irony of his misspelling 'divine' =D

Comment: [Great ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=anathematise&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canathematise%3B%2Cc0), though. ;^)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/specify-multiple-attribute-selectors-in-css

Answer (score 223, accepted):

`&&` works by stringing-together multiple selectors like-so:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>

div.class1.class2
{
  /* foo */
}
```

Another example:

```
<input type="radio" class="class1" />

input[type="radio"].class1
{
  /* foo */
}
```

`||` works by separating multiple selectors with commas like-so:

```
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>

div.class1,
div.class2
{
  /* foo */
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for light. I hate styling forms, but it's my task, and site isn't mine. I'll apply classes to inputs.

Comment: Here's a useful chart of what Internet Explorer supports: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#selectors

Comment: `not` seems to work from IE9 onwards (thanks to the chart supplied by @geofflee).

Comment: Are we really still concerned with supporting older versions of IE in 2018? Not even Microsoft does.

Comment: Agreed. It's been 8 years since this answer was posted. I have removed the outdated guidance about the :not() selector.

Answer (score 69):

AND (`&&`):

```
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"])
```

OR (`||`):

```
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio"]), 
   .registration_form_right input:not([type="checkbox"])
```

Comment: Nah, fail too. It'll apply 1 to 2 and 2 to 1

Comment: @KennyTM: Look. Using comma will do something like this: .registration_form_right input:not([type="radio"]) will apply to everything including checkbox, and .registration_form_right input:not([type="checkbox"]) will apply to everything, including radio

Comment: @Misiur: Of course. The 2nd is for the "OR" (a.k.a. `||`) case. Updated to clarify.

Comment: @KennyTM: What Misiur is trying to say is… Your "||" example is syntactically correct, but if you simplify the expression, it becomes just ".registration_form_right input" because the union of the two selectors includes all inputs.

Comment: @geo, @Mis: look, the *question* asked "I'll need to use || soon", so this is a way to construct a `||` out of the examples. Of course it becomes `.registration_form_right input` after simplification, but the essence is *you use the `,` as `||`*. You could use `input:not([type="radio"]), input:not([name="foo"])` for a nontrivial example.

Answer (score 34):

To select properties `a` AND `b` of a `X` element:

```
X[a][b]
```

To select properties `a` OR `b` of a `X` element:

```
X[a],X[b]
```

Comment: The above answer is what I needed thanks. e.g. <input type="input" name="is_it_still_happening" value="no"><style>input[name="is_it_still_happening"][value="no"] { border: solid 2px red}</style>

Answer (score 6):

If we want to look for a `div` that contains both *this* **AND** *that* in their `value` attribute, we can simply connect both conditions, like so:

```
div[value*="this"][value*="that"]
```

In case we want the `div` that contains either *this* **OR** *that*, you can use a comma between both conditions, like so:

```
div[value*="this"], div[value*="that"]
```

**Note**: You can use as much conditions as you like. This is in no way limited to 2 as shown in the example.

Answer (score 5):

The `:not` pseudo-class is not supported by IE. I'd got for something like this instead:

```
.registration_form_right input[type="text"],
.registration_form_right input[type="password"],
.registration_form_right input[type="submit"],
.registration_form_right input[type="button"] {
  ...
}
```

Some duplication there, but it's a small price to pay for higher compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if any one is stuck like me.
After going though the post and some hit and trial
this worked for me.

```
input:not([type="checkbox"])input:not([type="radio"])
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you soooo much. This answer saved my day: )

Answer (score 3):

Very old question I know, but since this is what came up on the top of my search results, I'll go ahead and answer it with modern day CSS.

Since 2021, all browsers are compatible with the `:is` and `:where` pseudo-classes. `:where` has 0 specificity, and `:is` takes on the specificity of its most specific argument. [<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#difference_between_is_and_where)

Thus, for the given example in the OP, you'd do either:

```css
input:not(:is([type='radio'],[type='checkbox']))
{
  /* your css declarations here */
}
```

OR

```css
input:not(:where([type='radio'],[type='checkbox']))
{
  /* your css declarations here */
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for - a modern approach. FMI see the MDN docs for [:is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) and [:where()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where)

Answer (score 2):

You can somehow reproduce the behavior of "OR" using & and :not.

```
SomeElement.SomeClass [data-statement="things are getting more complex"]  :not(:not(A):not(B))     {
    /* things aren't so complex for A or B */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, :not(:not) is not a valid CSS syntax. It works with jQuery though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you hate to write more selectors and divide them by a comma?

```
.registration_form_right input:not([type="radio"]),  
.registration_form_right input:not([type="checkbox"])  
{  
}
```

and BTW this

```
not([type="radio" && type="checkbox"])
```

looks to me more like "input which does not have both these types" :)

Comment: That wouldn't work, because the first selector would select all non- `radio`, (but _would_ select the `checkbox`), and the second would do the reverse. The union of the two would contain both `checkbox` _and_ `radio`.

Comment: That first example won't && them together, it'll fire for inputs that aren't radios for the first selector, AND inputs that aren't checkboxes, which means all inputs :-)

Comment: You're wrong. Then, first one will apply to second, and second, to first.

Answer (score 1):

A word of caution. Stringing together several `not` selectors increases the specificity of the resulting selector, which makes it harder to override: you'll basically need to find the selector with all the nots and copy-paste it into your new selector.

A `not(X or Y)` selector would be great to avoid inflating specificity, but I guess we'll have to stick to combining the opposites, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797109/5050045).