# Specify multiple attribute selectors in CSS

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors

What is the syntax for doing something like:

```
input[name="Sex" AND value="M"]
```

Basically, I want to select the `input` element that has the attribute `name="Sex"` as well as the attribute `value="M"`:

```html
<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="M" />
```

Elements such as the following should *not* be selected:

```
<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="F" />
```

Answer (score 698, accepted):

Simple `input[name=Sex][value=M]` would do pretty nice. And it's actually well-described in the [standard doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

> Multiple attribute selectors can be used to refer to several
>   attributes of an element, or even several times to the same attribute.
>
> Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute
>   has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has
>   exactly the value "Columbus":
>
> `span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }`

As a side note, using quotation marks around an attribute value is required only if this value is not a valid identifier.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3aZs/1/)

Comment: is there something like this, but OR instead of AND?

Comment: You mean other than `,` (comma)?

Comment: you can’t write span[hello="Cleveland"],[goodbye="Columbus"] but you have to repeat a (possibly long) part.

Comment: You have to indeed (at least for the moment), unless you use preprocessors. Consult [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944800/succinct-way-of-specifying-two-or-more-values-for-an-attribute-in-css-selector) for more details.

Comment: Please notice that there shouldn't be space symbols between two [][]

Answer (score 113):

For concatenating it's:

```
input[name="Sex"][value="M"] {}
```

And for taking union it's:

```
input[name="Sex"], input[value="M"] {}
```

Comment: With `:is()` pseudo-class, you can reduce duplication with the union: `input:is([name="Sex"],[value="M"])`

Answer (score 38):

Concatenate the attribute selectors:

```
input[name="Sex"][value="M"]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that at least one of the attribute values must be quoted.  This would fail if you wrote it as
    `input[name=Sex][value=M]`
even though it would be valid to have a selector with only one attribute that didn't use quotes.

Comment: @stevec Did you mean to put this on the accepted answer?  I've quoted the values in my answer.  I also don't think that's true.  You need quotes if the answer contains certain characters but not in this example. https://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes

Comment: I added that note because I tried it in several browsers without quotes and it failed in all.  I believe that the issue is that without quotes on at least one, it is ambiguous because it could be interpreted as an input whose name is `Sex][value=M`

Comment: @stevec brackets are invalid in unquoted attributes for that exact reason. This example works in Firefox and Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/o2abekdh/3/

Answer (score 8):

Just to add that there should be no space between the selector and the opening bracket.

The following will trigger every `td` with an attribute named `attr`

```
td[attr]
```

The following will trigger every elements inside a `td` with an attribute named `attr` (not the td itself)

```
td [attr]
```