# Properties combination in Qt stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I wrote Qt4 (or Qt5) class MyButton and defined two boolean properties, like this:

```
#include <QPushButton>

class MyButton : QPushButton
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(bool property_1 READ property_1)
  Q_PROPERTY(bool property_2 READ property_2)
public:
  explicit MyButton(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ...
}
```

Now I want to customize application stylesheet in external file so that in different combinations of this properties MyButton has different background color. Separately this works well:

```
MyButton[property_1="true"] { background-color: black }
MyButton[property_2="true"] { background-color: white }
```

So the question is: how to combine few properties in the same condition with "and", "or" and "not" operations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is the same as [CSS attribute selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/css-multiple-attribute-selector).

Thus `property_1="true"` AND `property_2="true"` condition is:

```css
MyButton[property_1="true"][property_2="true"] { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The OR operation is achieved with a comma between the selectors.

For example:

```css
MyButton[property_1="true"],[property_2="true"] { background-color: red; }
```