# How to add multiple attributes in CSS in input element

Tags: html, css

Ss this allow in CSS, if not then how to achieve this criteria.
I want to get specific input to be modified for this CSS.

**CSS**

```
<style>
input[type=radio name=rbl value=1]{
//something here
}


</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<input type="radio" name="rbl" value="1" />One // I want this to be modified
<input type="text" name="txt" />

</body>
```

Comment: This post already handles this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/css-multiple-attribute-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple attribute selector can be done like this:

```
input[type="radio"][name="rbl"][value="1"]{
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

Here, the CSS will be applied to `input type radio` which has `name rbl` and `value 1`

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p4tqmq5g/) for the same.

Comment: still same issue, not returning anything

Comment: Ok ok done. it was my mistake, I have palced a space before :checked

Comment: Thanks for kind quick reply and help

Comment: I have also added a fiddle for the same.