# How do I match an element with only specific attributes and nothing else using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assuming example elements:

```
<a href="..." rel="...">...
<a href="..." rel="..." target="...">...
```

How can I match only the first element? I would like to tell jQuery to match only the `<a>` element which has an `href` and a `rel` attribute, but no other attributes. `:not()` requires me to mention specific attributes to exclude, but what about unknown ones?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12340737/8252164
Multiple attribute selectors

Comment: @CBroe good point. It seems performing an exclusive selector with `:not()` is your only choice, other than applying specific classes (which would be better in the long run)

Comment: This feels a bit [XY problem-y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) … can you explain _why_ you would need to select an element based specifically on those criteria? Maybe there’s other ways. Or maybe at least the amount of non-allowed attributes can be limited to a certain set?

Comment: Agree with @CBroe . Seems like an unusual requirement

Comment: I agree, it is an unusual requirement and that's what brings me here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use filter() and check the attributes length. Note that adding anything like  class or data attributes would mean you would need to modify this

```js
$('a[href][rel]').filter(function(){
   return this.attributes.length === 2;  
}).css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" rel="foo" target="_blank"> Has target</a>
<a href="#" rel="foo" > No target</a>
<a href="#"  > No rel </a>
```

Comment: I had frowned upon other `filter` uses, because it simply felt like a shortcut for a `forEach` loop, but this bit is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) and [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) function for this, to select the first element in a collection & filter out the unwanted elements.

Example:

```
$("a[href][rel]").not("[target]").first();
```

In order to exclude items that contain other unknown attributes, you should use filter as the other answers advise.

This wouldn't be a good solution however, it would be much better to add a class to the elements you need to select, or have them in another div.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with test condition to check element has only attributes length

```js
$('a[href][rel]').filter(function() {
  return this.attributes.length == 2
}).addClass('a');
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="..." rel="...">...</a>
<a href="..." rel="..." target="...">...</a>
```

Comment: You were also too late ;)

Comment: @mplungjan, Yeah, didn't shaw charlietfl's answer and now can't delete answer (quota issue)

Comment: @mplungjan, nope

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.hasAttribute` and further check `this.attributes.length === 2` to confirm that `<a>` element has only two attributes:

```js
$('a').each(function(){
   if(this.attributes.length == 2 && this.hasAttribute("href") && this.hasAttribute("rel")){
     $(this).addClass('selected');
   }
});
```

```css
.selected{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="..." rel="...">1111</a>
<a href="..." rel="..." target="...">222</a>
<a href="..." rel="...">333</a>
<a href="..." rel="..." target="...">444</a>
```

Comment: `$('a[href][rel]')` is more elegant

Comment: @mplungjan yes, I just showed that this could be also done.