# Apply CSS rule to elements matching one of multiple possible attribute values

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply `css` rule for multiple values of `html` attribute.

I've tried to apply it like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/specify-multiple-attribute-selectors-in-css), with no success:

```css
input[name="a"][name="b"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="a"> <!-- should be hidden -->
<input name="b"> <!-- should be hidden -->
<input name="c"> <!-- should not be hidden -->
```

The rule isn't applied at all.

However, when I use only one attribute selector, it works for that one matching element:

```css
input[name="a"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="a"> <!-- is hidden -->
<input name="b"> <!-- is not hidden -->
```

What am I doing wrong / is there any way to define it except duplicating rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them separately and use a comma in between like below.

This code applies the css to `input[name="a"]` **and/or** `input[name="b"]`.

Look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors) to find out more.

**Note:** I used `background-color: red;` instead of `display: none;` so you can see the difference. To suit your problem, change it back to `display: none;`

```css
input[name="a"], input[name="b"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input name="a" />
<input name="b" />
<input name="c" />
```