# d3.js - Select node element based on attributes value using .selectAll()

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, filter

I've the a node like:

```
<div>
  <svg ...>
    <g class="graph">
      <path class="myarea" d="...AAA..." pos="p1">  </path>
    </g>
    <g class="graph">
      <path class="myarea" d="...BBB..." pos="p2">  </path>
    </g>
    <g class="graph">
      <path class="myarea" d="...CCC..." pos="p3">  </path>
    </g>
  /svg>
</div>
```

I am trying to select a specific node (*e.g where d="...BBB..."*) which has the attribute  `pos='p2'`

```
d3.selectAll(".myarea").each(function(d,i) {
   console.log("-> ",  d3.select(this).attr("pos"), d3.select(this).attr("pos") == 'p2' );
  
});
```

This produces/returns an arrays with all 3 entries:

> -> p0 false
>
> -> p1 true
>
> -> p2 false
>
> -> [Array(3)]

I am interested in selecting just one, in this case the one with `.attr("pos") == 'p2'` so I'd like to return just one element.

I've tried with `map()` and `filter()` but without success.

What is the correct way to select a specific element based on an attribute value?

Comment: Can you not use something like `d3.selectAll(".myarea[d='BBB'][pos='p2']")`, D3 supports any valid css selector, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5324415/7106086) (matching single attributes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12340737/7106086) (matching multiple attributes)

Comment: Nice, that works. did not know about that syntax `.select(.myarea[pos='p2']")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Selection.filter()**

You *could* select a bunch of elements based on class, and then filter the selection with `selection.filter()`:

```
svg.selectAll("whatever")
  .filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("col") == 2; // filter by single attribute
  })
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("col") == 2
  })
  .attr("fill","orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="5" y="5" col="1" row="1"></rect>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="30" y="5" col="2" row="1" ></rect>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="5" y="30" col="1" row="2" ></rect>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="30" y="30" col="2" row="2" ></rect>
</svg>
```

**Using CSS selectors to select by attribute value**

But, rather than selecting a bunch of elements and then filtering the selection, we can do everything in one step with the CSS selectors described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5324415/7106086). This lets us select elements an attribute they have is equal to a specific value:

```
svg.selectAll("rect[col='2']")
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("rect[col='2']")
  .attr("fill","orange");
  
d3.selectAll("rect[col='1'][row='1']")
  .attr("fill","steelblue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="5" y="5" col="1" row="1"></rect>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="30" y="5" col="2" row="1" ></rect>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="5" y="30" col="1" row="2" ></rect>
  <rect width="20" height="20" x="30" y="30" col="2" row="2" ></rect>
</svg>
```

In the above I also use:

```
d3.selectAll("rect[col='1'][row='1']") to select based on two attribute values.
```

You can also substitute look for a class rather than a generic tag, so for you this might look like:

```
d3.selectAll(".myarea[d='BBB'][pos='p2']")
```