# d3: Finding specific node and executing .dispatch

Tags: d3.js, onclick

I am trying to select a specific node in my force directed graph and executing an .on("click", clicked) attribute.

The *clicked* function sets an active state to the node and opens a modal with information about that node.

The function that will trigger this active state is itself triggered through an anchor/hyperlink in a given modal showing a node's information.

```
<a class='modal-AuthorPrimary' id='" + aP + " (hyperlink)' href='#null' onclick='nodeHyperLink()'>" + authorPrimary + "</a>
```

The anchor/hyperlink is triggering the function properly as I have tested it with an alert message.

```
 function nodeHyperLink () {

 var aP = "test text";

 return alert(aP);

 }
```

I have tried selecting the specific node using the method suggested here (d3.selectAll(class+id)): [d3.js - Select node element based on attributes value using .selectAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701387/d3-js-select-node-element-based-on-attributes-value-using-selectall).

```
 var triggeredNode = d3.selectAll(".circle[data-id='nodeID']")
```

I have tried using a filter function suggested as a solution to the same question.

```
 var triggeredNode = d3.selectAll("nodes")
     .filter(function() {
 return d3.select(this).attr("id") === "nodeID";
 })
```

In both cases, I have also tried to trigger the *clicked* function using the .dispatch method (recommended here: [How to invoke "click" event programmatically in d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmatically-in-d3)).

```
triggeredNode.dispatch("click")
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated!