# TestCafe: Is it possible to use the selector to find elements by Row and Col

Tags: html, css, testcafe

Just wondering if anyone had any experience using the selector in testcafe to find the col & row

I would like to select this element by row and col, is this possible.

```
<td class="text-left" style="background: #5594AA;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;" row="0" col="Monday"><!--!--><!--!--><!--!-->        <button class="btn btn-sm dx-btn dx-btn-text rtv-cell-filling-button" id="id892d282d-3723-4a09-b708-913a7f76814c" type="button"><!--!-->
            <!--!--><div><!--!--><i class="far fa-sun" aria-hidden="true"></i>09:00 - 17:00</div><!--!-->
        </button><!--!-->
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally spoken, you can select an element by any attribute that an DOM element has via [TestCafe's Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html). To select the given tabledata element by multiple attributes, you could make use of how CSS-Selectors select elements with multiple attributes:

```js
const myTableDataSelector = Selector("td[row=0][col=Monday]");
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/specify-multiple-attribute-selectors-in-css) on the usage of multiple css selectors to select specific elements.