# How can i select disabled input which has one more attribute?

Tags: html, css

If i want to select input with type checkbox and which is disabled i use

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled/>
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled
```

but i need now to select input with secondary attribute for example

How can i insert here also the :greyed-out ?

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled greyed-out />
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled ...
```

Comment: Just add another attribute selector: `input[type="checkbox"][greyed-out]:disabled`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify multiple attribute selectors in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/specify-multiple-attribute-selectors-in-css)

Comment: Having a non-standard attribute `greyed-out` is rather ugly, btw. - that should rather be a custom data attribute. (If it is not better handled by a class to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

yeah as CBroe commented use **input[type="checkbox"][greyed-out]:disabled**