# Identify previous CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to identify previous CSS?

The focus here is the `card` class.

Example:

```
<div class="app">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card">
                <label for="">Title</label>
                <div class="number">
                    120
                </div>
    
                <div class="number">
                    Blah blah blah
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="sm-6 md-6 lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <label for="">Title</label>
                    <div class="number">
                        120
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="number">
                        Blah blah blah
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

In the `first row` the class `card` is alone. In the `second row` the class name is inside a column represented by class `sm-6 md-6 lg-6`.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to apply a CSS to `card` that is only in `sm, md or lg`?

Thanks.

Comment: `.sm-6 > .card, .md-6 > card, .lg-6 > .card {}`

Comment: You can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has , But it's not yet supported widely.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini No it doesn't work in any browser as you can see here: https://caniuse.com/?search=has

Comment: @Joel and what I said?

Comment: you said "Use can use this", but you can't. since it doesn't work in any browser.... Also, how is "not widely  supported" === 0% of browsers?

Comment: @Joel it is possible to identify the class name only by the letters `sm, md, lg`, because each letter has a number up to 12...lol?

Comment: You can do: `[class^="md-"]` instead of `md-6` and it will match all classes starting with md-

Comment: @Joel Would it be this? `[class^="sm-"], [class^="md-"], [class^="lg-"] .card{
    background-color: #000;
}`

Comment: No, it would not be, because with that you would be selecting all elements with a class starting with `sm-` or `md-` (and applying the background color to _those_); and `.card` elements only if they were nested inside an element with a class starting with `lg-`.

Comment: `div[class^="sm-"][class^="md-"][class^="lg-"] > .card ( background-color: #000; }`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/specify-multiple-attribute-selectors-in-css and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: @TylerH how to identify the first one, the ones in the middle and the last one? Ex: jsfiddle.net/x1f4oLrn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, if you don't want to style all sizes you can do:

```
div[class^="sm-"] > .card {
    // styles all classes starting with sm-* and where the first
    // child element has the class .card
}
div[class^="md-"] > .card {
    // style    
}
div[class^="lg-"] > .card {
    // style
}
```

Or one rule for all cases:

```
div[class^="sm-"] > .card, div[class^="md-"] > .card, div[class^="lg-"] > .card {
 // styles card when its a child to a sm md or lg class
}
```

What does this do?

`[]` selects an elements attribute, in this case `[class]`

`^` means *starts with*

Comment: You can make the second rule more efficient by just combining the attribute selectors.

Comment: Last order, how to identify the first one, the ones in the middle and the last one? Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/x1f4oLrn/

Answer (score 0):

CSS to `.card` that is a child of either `sm-6`, `md-6` or `lg-6` class.

```
   .sm-6 .card, .md-6 .card, .lg-6 .card {
      background-color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.sm-6 .card, .md-6 .card, .lg-6 .card {
      color:white;
    }
```

Comment: As Tiago mentions in the comments under the question, the selector needs to allow for Bootstrap size classes with values other than `6`.

Comment: You need to add details and how this code works as well. You can't just type some code. You need to give a proper explanation.