# Ruby Cucumber using OR

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm testing a poorly written webpage where on one page the first heading is a H1 then on the next page it's a H2.

Usually I would write something like `find('h1', text: 'bla bla bla')` or `expect(find('h1')).to have_text 'bla bla bla'`

As it keeps changing between H1 and H2, is there a way to say `find('h1' || 'h2', text: 'bla bla bla)`

I'd like to keep the test looking within the headers as the text sometimes exists within the body of the page too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS "and" and "or"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797091/css-and-and-or)

Comment: As Dave mentioned, this is a duplicate you just didn't know it. It's really a CSS selector question, not a cucumber or ruby question.

Comment: As a tester, I'd give to the developer as "which is one wrong, h1 OR h2?", then turn in a defect.

Comment: It has been raised but with other work going on, it's been pretty much pushed to bottom of the backlog.  I was just wondering if you could use 'or' within the find command when scoping to a css selector.  It doesn't look like you can.