# querySelectorAll with two conditions on data attribute

Tags: javascript

I have two data attributes (let's call them data-foo && data-bar). And i'd like to do something like that `document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="hey"] **AND** [data-bar="ho"])`. I know how to do a **OR** but i can't find how to **AND** with selectors. Can you please help ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="hey"][data-bar="ho"]')`

Comment: Since those are css selectors - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797091/css-and-and-or

Comment: [Can I put logical operators in document.querySelectorAll? If so, how?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36544941)

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny that did the trick.