# CSS selecting combining multiple selectors

Tags: html, css

(Not quite related to [CSS "and" and "or"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797091/css-and-and-or), or [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), as I am trying to achieve different goal here - either `and`ing two selectors or creating a different `HTML` structure that **can** be  used by `css` to solve my problem)

Hi,
I wanted to know if there is any plausible way in CSS to make a logical `AND` between selectors. This seems quite easy when I only refer to one DOM element, but when I try referring to many, the whole concept becomes much harder.

I'll give my example:

I have the following HTML structure, representing an accordion:

```html
<div id="holder">
    <div id="toggle">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="data" class="show|hide">
    </div>
</div>
```

(BTW, I am using the bootstrap logic for the accordion, so I prefer not changing a lot in the given structure)

I want to set `#content::after` depending on whether `hide` or `show` are the active state.

This could be converted to the following statement:

```css
#hodler > #data.show && #holder > #toggle > #content::after
```

However, this is an invalid syntax. Moreover, CSS does not parent selector.
Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS cannot select elements that come before the current element in the selector, so you would need to move the `.show/hide` element to be before the `#toggle` element. That way, you'd be able to do `#holder>#data.show~#toggle>#content::after`

Comment: @CBroe I prefer not giving another structure to the document as I use bootstrap and they might frown upon it. And also, the questions in StackOverflow intended for the whole community and therefore seeking a general solution is the better approach.

Comment: I don’t get how this is a problem to begin with then - Bootstrap sets appropriate classes on these elements to identify whether they are in an open or collapsed state.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with just CSS and the current HTML.

If the order of the `#toggle` and `#data` elements were reversed, you could use the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) like this:

```html
<div id="holder">
    <div id="data" class="show|hide"></div>
    <div id="toggle">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#data.show + #toggle #content:after { /* show styles */ }
#data.hide + #toggle #content:after { /* hide styles */ }
```