# How to apply previous substyle into other style?

Tags: css, sass

How can add `input` properties to `select` also? Something wrong with this syntax.

```css
.nestedContainerForContactForm {
    div {
        input {
            width: 100%;
        }
        &select {
            outline: none;
            -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want both input and select elements to have width: 100%? Same way you normally express "or" in CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2797091/3001761.

Comment: Yes, kind of like `or`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to write it would be like this:

```
.nestedContainerForContactForm {
  div {
    input,
    select {
      width: 100%;
    }
    select {
      outline: none;
      -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    }
  }
}
```